# Running across a subset of a list in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to run through a subset in a python list?

I have the following problem, I have two lists, `list1` is very long and `list2` is quite short. Now, I want to check which elements of the `list2` are also in `list1`.  My current version looks like this:

```
for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
        # do something
```

This takes a very long time. Is it possible to get a subset and then run through the list?

I need to do this many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the list elements are [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-hashable), you can find the intersection using [*sets*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
>>> for x in set(list2).intersection(list1):
        print x
```

If they are not hashable, you can at least speed-up the search by [sorting](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) the shorter list and doing [bisected lookups](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/bisect.html#module-bisect):

```
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> list2.sort()
>>> n = len(list2)
>>> for x in list1:
        i = bisect_left(list2, x)
        if i != n and list2[i] == x:
            print x
```

If your data elements are neither hashable nor sortable, then you won't be able to speed-up your original code:

```
>>> for x in list1:
        if x in list2:
            print x
```

The running time of the set-intersection approach is proportional to the sum of lengths of the two lists, `O(n1 + n2)`.   The running time of the bisected-search approach is `O((n1 + n2) * log(n2))`.   The running time of the original brute-force approach is `O(n1 * n2)`.

Comment: Sorting will not work in py3x if the list contains objects of different types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sets` here, they provide `O(1)` lookup compared to `O(N)` by lists.
But sets expect that the items must be hashable(immutable).

```
s = set(list1)
for item in lis2:
    if item in s:
       #do something
```

Comment: +1, but of course that only works if all elements of `list1` are hashable.

Comment: @TimPietzcker And list2's elements must be hashable too, otherwise `item in s` will raise `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shorthand

```
list3 = [l for l in list1 if l in list2]
```

if your list has elements that repeat

```
l2 = list(set(list2))
l1 = list(set(list1))

list3 = [l for l l1 if l in l2]
```